# Bernoulli trial given probability of success - missile hitting a target problem

Tags: probability

A missile has a $25$% chance of hitting a target. How many missiles  must be fired to ensure that there is a greater than $90$% chance that the target will be hit at least once?

Been using the binomial distribution formula, but can't seem to get the answer?

Comment: Would you add what you have done about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $P(\text{at least one success}) \geq 0.9$

This is the same as $1-P(\text{no successes}) \geq 0.9$

Then you can find that $P(\text{no successes}) \leq 0.1$

where the sign flip because we divide both sides by $-1$.

For an unknown number of trials $n$, we have that

$P(\text{no successes}) = .75^n$.

Then

$$\begin{align*}
log(.75^n) \leq log(0.1)
& \Rightarrow nlog(.75) \leq log(0.1) \\\\
&\Rightarrow n \geq \frac{log(0.1)}{log(0.75)} \text{ (sign flips because } log(.75) \lt 0\\\\
&\Rightarrow n \geq 8.004
\end{align*}$$

But we cannot have $8.004$ trials which means it must be $9$.

Checking in R:

```
1-dbinom(0, 9, .25)

0.9249153
```

So this probability indeed exceeds $0.9$.

Note that we come really close to having a $90$% chance of hitting the target at least once if we fire $8$ missiles.

```
1-dbinom(0, 8, .25)

0.8998871
```

Comment: great thanks a million!!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of times the target is hit, $n$ be the number of missiles fired, and $p=0.25$ be the probability that a missile hits the target. Then $X\sim \text{Binom}(n,p)$.

You wish to find the smallest $n$ so that $P(X\geq 1) \geq 0.9$. So we must calculate $P(X \geq 1)$. The easiest way to do this is to write it as $P(X \geq 1) = 1-P(X=0)$. Then the problem becomes finding the smallest $n$ so that $P(X=0) \leq 0.1$. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: yes thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative basic approach.** If there is a greater than $\frac{9}{10}$ chance of hitting the target at least once, there must be a less than $\frac{1}{10}$ chance of never hitting the target.  Then:

- A single missile has a $\frac34$ chance of missing the target.
- Two missiles have a $\frac34 \times \frac34 = \frac{9}{16}$ chance of missing the target.
- Three missiles have a $\left(\frac34\right)^3 = \frac{27}{64}$ chance of missing the target.

When does this probability drop below $\frac{1}{10}$?  Use logs to finish this answer off.

ETA: We assume the missiles' chances are independent.  In real life, this isn't necessarily a warranted assumption.